# Remote Spark Connection - Scala: Could not find BlockManagerMaster

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark Master and Worker, both are running in localhost. I have started Master and Worker node by triggering command:

```
sbin/start-all.sh
```

Logs for master node invocation:

```
Spark Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -cp /Users/gaurishi/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/Users/gaurishi/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host 192.168.0.38 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

Logs for Worker node invocation:

```
Spark Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -cp /Users/gaurishi/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/Users/gaurishi/spark/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://192.168.0.38:7077
```

I have following configuration in **conf/spark-env.sh**

```
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=192.168.0.38
```

Content of /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Scala code, that I am invoking to establish remote spark connection:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(AppConstants.AppName)
  .setMaster("spark://192.168.0.38:7077")

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName(AppConstants.AppName)
  .config(sparkConf)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

While executing code from IDE, I am getting following exception in console:

```
2018-10-04 14:43:33,426 ERROR [main] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logError(91)) - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
........
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find BlockManagerMaster.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postLocalMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
.......
2018-10-04 14:43:33,432 INFO  [stop-spark-context] spark.SparkContext (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
........
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find BlockManagerMaster.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postLocalMessage(Dispatcher.scala:132)
........
```

Logs from /logs/master shows following error:

```
18/10/04 14:43:13 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1835832137613908542, local class serialVersionUID = -1329125091869941550
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        .......
```

What changes should be done to connect spark remotely?

Spark Versions:

```
Spark: spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Build dependencies:

```
Scala: 2.11
Spark-hive: 2.2.2
Maven-org-spark-project-hive hive-metastore = 1.x;
```

Logs:

[Console log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dEs_wSxYY_EcVmzwuSiycEB6jLraHY1W/view?usp=sharing)
[Spark Master-Node log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18oXCaQ5Y_NzMm9MUVwUcA2wMey_SBYky/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Using hostname(ie. 186590dbe5bd.ant.abc.com) in place of IP address(ie. 192.168.0.38) is throwing different exception : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648467/remote-spark-connection-scala-nullpointerexception-on-registerblockmanager
I don't know if issue is same or different so creating separate question for this on SO

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post. But, sharing my answer to save someone else precious time.

I was facing a similar issue two days back, and after so much of hacking, I found the root cause for the problem was the Scala version I was using in my Maven project.

I was using Spark 2.4.3, and it's internally using Scala 2.11, and the Scala project I was using was compiled with Scala 2.12. This Scala version mismatch was the reason for the above error.

When I downgraded the Scala version in my Maven project, it started working. Hope it helps.